# Cannot perform Click on 'Hidden Control' in Coded UI tests

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am using web application. When I play back my test, it fails at clicking on the hyper link. I tried drawhighlight and finding matching controls but no luck. Please find the error details:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Web'
ControlType:  'Pane'
Id:  'ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cntBody_cntBody_cntBody_listUsers_lblAdd'
Name:  ''
TagName:  'SPAN'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F002
```

Comment: If I had to look at your control id, it looks like it has a deep lookup chain. Are you sure the control is indeed visible?

Comment: Hi JL, it is indeed visible on the page but rendered as Anchor tag.The control used in the page is image button.

Comment: Make sure your control defintion (tyrpe, name , id,...) are correct and that your control enabled when you are trying to select it. Also maybe there is a pop-up blocking??

Answer (score 0):

I had a tough time clicking on a Pane and wrote a method that gets the coordinates of the center point of the Pane. Then you can just click that point.

```
public Point getCenterPointOfUITestContol(UITestControl Object) {
    Rectangle rectangle = Object.BoundingRectangle;
    Point point = new Point(0, 0);
    point.X = rectangle.X + (rectangle.Width / 2);
    point.Y = rectangle.Y + (rectangle.Height / 2);
    return point;
}
```

If your Pane comes back with coordinates of -1 then it really is hidden.